# Error: Could not find module jquery (Emberjs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ember.js, gruntjs

When accessing the home page of my ember website, The page does not load and gives me this error in the console:

```
Error: Could not find module jquery ember.js:251
TypeError: Ember.DataAdapter is undefined ember-data.js:4529
TypeError: Ember.Handlebars is undefined compiled-templates.js:1
TypeError: Ember.Route is undefined combined-scripts.js:19
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined affix.js:126
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined alert.js:98
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined dropdown.js:154
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined tooltip.js:386
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined modal.js:246
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined transition.js:56
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined button.js:109
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined popover.js:117
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined carousel.js:217
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined scrollspy.js:158
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined collapse.js:179
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined tab.js:135
"DEBUG: For more advanced debugging, install the Ember Inspector from https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ember-inspector/" ember.js:3521
```

I have used yeoman to generate an ember project. and one of my changes (I'm not sure which one, maybe a css change) has caused this error to suddenly occur.

I have checked the dependencies using `bower list` as shown below, and can confirm jQuery is in there:

```
myapp#0.0.0 /usr/local/src/myapp
├─┬ bootstrap-sass#3.0.2
│ └── jquery#2.1.0 (2.1.1-beta1 available)
├─┬ ember#1.5.0 (latest is 1.6.0-beta.2)
│ ├── handlebars#1.2.1 (1.3.0 available, latest is 2.0.0-alpha.2)
│ └── jquery#2.1.0 (latest is 2.1.1-beta1)
├─┬ ember-data#1.0.0-beta.7
│ └─┬ ember#1.5.0 (1.6.0-beta.2 available)
│   ├── handlebars#1.2.1
│   └── jquery#2.1.0
├── ember-mocha-adapter#0.1.2 (latest is 0.2.0)
├── handlebars#1.2.1 (latest is 2.0.0-alpha.2)
├── holderjs#2.3.2
└── jquery#2.1.0 (2.1.1-beta1 available)
```

I am new to javascript development and would appreciate any knowledge as to what might be the problem.

---

**UPDATE:**

One of the grunt tasks that occur during the build is taking the index.html file copied from my source folder (into .tmp), and replacing it's contents with references to the correct dependencies:

```
Found a block:
        <!-- build:js(app) scripts/components.js -->
        <script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/handlebars/handlebars.runtime.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/ember/ember.prod.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/ember-data/ember-data.prod.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
Updating config with the following assets:
    - app/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js
    - app/bower_components/handlebars/handlebars.runtime.js
    - app/bower_components/ember/ember.prod.js
    - app/bower_components/ember-data/ember-data.prod.js
```

Here it shows that the given assets, including jquery is loaded. Jquery is 2.1.0 and ember is 1.5.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was due to a change that occured in the jquery dependency since the last version, The jquery.js file is now located under the dist folder of the bower installation.

i.e.

```
<script src="bower_components/dist/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
```

I have submitted my change as a pull request [ember yeoman generator on github](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-ember/pull/211) (It's been merged already)